# Increasing swipe back threshold in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm trying to implement a back feature like Instagram(where you can swipe back even with swiping from the middle of the screen on iOS). The current swipe back happens just by swiping from the most left/right part of the screen and I'm trying to make it easier to swipe back.

I understand that the question is a little ambiguous but I couldn't find code related to my problem and I think if you just push a page with the `Navigator.push` function in flutter and try to swipe back to the last page, you can understand what I mean.

Comment: I really need this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package called [swipeable_page_route](https://pub.dev/packages/swipeable_page_route).

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  SwipeablePageRoute(
    builder: (context) => const FollowInfoScreen(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).